# Rstudio/windows, drag and drop to open .R files

Tags: rstudio

Nothing happens when I drag a .R file in windows file explorer and drop it to Rstudio editor window.

Is there any configuration in Rstudio to allow this or is it for some reason not supported by Rstudio?

Comment: It's not supported, but maybe you can contact RStudio developers in order to implement it in future versions.

Answer (score 1):

There's an open issue about this [at the RStudio github repo](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4037) since December 2018 - an enhancement suggested by an RStudio engineer. It did receive good community attention and support, but anyone interested can still cast an additional 'thumbs up' there.

Also, this is currently [marked as part of the 'Electron'](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/7389) RStudio epic which is currently under work, so it seems a safe bet it will be included in the next release.